# strptime() equivalent on Windows?

Tags: c++, c, windows, datetime

Is there a good equivalent implementation of `strptime()` available for Windows?  Unfortunately, this POSIX function does not appear to be available.

[Open Group description of strptime](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html) - summary: it converts a text string such as `"MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:SS"` into a `tm struct`, the opposite of `strftime()`.

Comment: It would help if you added a description of strptime so I don't have to google it :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An open-source version (BSD license) of `strptime()` can be found here: http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/lib/libc/time/strptime.c?rev=HEAD

You'll need to add the following declaration to use it:

```
char *strptime(const char * __restrict, const char * __restrict, struct tm * __restrict);
```

Comment: Visual Studio 2008 complains that "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sys/cdefs.h': No such file or directory"

Comment: How is that the accepted answer. It uses a bunch headers which are not included in windows.

Comment: This solution does not work on Windows (and on Linux or macOS it isn't needed!)

Answer (score 36):

If you don't want to port any code or condemn your project to boost, you can do this:

1. parse the date using `sscanf`
2. then copy the integers into a `struct tm` (subtract 1 from month and 1900 from year -- months are 0-11 and years start in 1900)
3. finally, use `mktime` to get a UTC epoch integer

Just remember to set the `isdst` member of the `struct tm` to -1, or else you'll have daylight savings issues.

Comment: Note, that `mktime` works with dates in range about 1970 ~ 2038, but you can use [`_mktime64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1y53h2a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which works with dates in range 1970 ~ 3000 :)

Comment: Sometimes it makes sense to fill `isdst` with its current value, you can get it with `localtime(&current_time)->tm_isdst;`, where `current_time` is current time in `time_t` format, as returned by `time(&current_time)`.

Comment: @amwinter how about tm_wday and tm_yday ?

Comment: @aderchox simply use mktime() to normalize the time and you will get a correct tm_wday and tm_yday.

Comment: Ad 2. Not needed if sscan into &t.tm_day directly
Remember to zero init the struct e.g.: struct tm my_time{0};

Comment: Avoid setting `tm_isdst = -1;` I wrote about that at length here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558919/mktime-and-tm-isdst

Answer (score 31):

Assuming you are using Visual Studio 2015 or above, you can use this as a drop-in replacement for strptime:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

extern "C" char* strptime(const char* s,
                          const char* f,
                          struct tm* tm) {
  // Isn't the C++ standard lib nice? std::get_time is defined such that its
  // format parameters are the exact same as strptime. Of course, we have to
  // create a string stream first, and imbue it with the current C locale, and
  // we also have to make sure we return the right things if it fails, or
  // if it succeeds, but this is still far simpler an implementation than any
  // of the versions in any of the C standard libraries.
  std::istringstream input(s);
  input.imbue(std::locale(setlocale(LC_ALL, nullptr)));
  input >> std::get_time(tm, f);
  if (input.fail()) {
    return nullptr;
  }
  return (char*)(s + input.tellg());
}
```

Just be aware that for cross platform applications, `std::get_time` wasn't implemented until GCC 5.1, so switching to calling `std::get_time` directly may not be an option.

Comment: Thanks for being copy-pastable.

Comment: but std::get_time is broken on VS2015 [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35041344/trying-to-use-stdget-time-to-parse-yymmdd-and-failing#comment69466398_35041344)

Comment: It isn't broken; what they were trying to do doesn't work with GCC or Clang either, and, although I've not specifically tested it, it likely doesn't work with strptime either.

Comment: +1 but to get it to work I needed to add the following line after the `get_time()` line:  `if(input.eof()) return (char *)(s + strlen(s));`

Comment: There's a difference in behavior between these two (GCC11 and end-of-2021 glibc and STL): This C++ versions rejects `strptime("2018-11-41", "%Y-%m-%d", x)`, returning a `nullptr`, while the C version succeeds, leaving the trailing `"1"` unparsed.

Comment: As i was using this function a lot i noticed that `std::locale(setlocale(LC_ALL, nullptr))` was slowing down the function by a lot, so you may want to take it outside the function in a variable et reuse the value each time instead of re-instanciating it at every call.

Answer (score 15):

This does the job:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp"
using namespace boost::posix_time;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::string ts("2002-01-20 23:59:59.000");
    ptime t(time_from_string(ts));
    tm pt_tm = to_tm( t );
```

Notice, however, that the input string is YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 0):

This is a copy-and-paste-capable C example of [the answer @amwinter posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3137634/4756299), although I did not use `sscanf()` - the `*scanf()` family of functions is IMO too perverse to do robust parsing with:

(headers and error checking omitted to keep the example short enough to prevent a vertical scroll bar from getting created)

```
    // format will be YYYYmmddHHMMSSZ
    const char *notAfter = getNotAfterStringFromX509Cert( x509 );
    struct tm notAfterTm = { 0 };

#ifdef _WIN32
    char buffer[ 8 ];

    memset( buffer, 0, sizeof( buffer ) );
    strncpy( buffer, notAfter, 4 );
    notAfterTm.tm_year = strtol( buffer, NULL, 10 ) - 1900;

    memset( buffer, 0, sizeof( buffer ) );
    strncpy( buffer, notAfter + 4, 2 );
    notAfterTm.tm_mon = strtol( buffer, NULL, 10 ) - 1;

    memset( buffer, 0, sizeof( buffer ) );
    strncpy( buffer, notAfter + 6, 2 );
    notAfterTm.tm_mday = strtol( buffer, NULL, 10 );

    memset( buffer, 0, sizeof( buffer ) );
    strncpy( buffer, notAfter + 8, 2 );
    notAfterTm.tm_hour = strtol( buffer, NULL, 10 );

    memset( buffer, 0, sizeof( buffer ) );
    strncpy( buffer, notAfter + 10, 2 );
    notAfterTm.tm_min = strtol( buffer, NULL, 10 );

    memset( buffer, 0, sizeof( buffer ) );
    strncpy( buffer, notAfter + 12, 2 );
    notAfterTm.tm_sec = strtol( buffer, NULL, 10 );

    time_t result = mktime( &notAfterTm );
```

This is a really simple case, where the input string is in a format known exactly, so it's extremely easy to parse.

Answer (score 0):

To my surprise, if not unbelievable, after at least 50 years of digital data processing there still seems no acceptable solution for a 'strptime()' method being available.

The following features describe what should be implemented to be acceptable:

- Integration of time zone information
- Portable code (preferably using ANSI C)
- Thread safety
- No dependency of additional libraries

Very helpful additional features are:

- Language support
- Option for parsing calendrical strings without the need of a format string
- Format string and function parameters compatible with the standard C 'strftime' definition (as far as possible)

None of the above presented solutions do fulfill the first four features although they are reasonable to my opinion. Using the standard C++ library <chrono> might make the 'strptime' function obsolete, but for me this library is quite confusing and not easy to use.

For those reasons I designed the following two implementions being consistent to each other and providing all above mentioned features.

- LibOb_strftime()
- LibOb_strptime()

They are published on github within a repository named

[strptime-for-Windows-Linux](https://github.com/OlafSimon/strptime-for-Windows-Linux).

Both functions amoung others are provided by just two files (LibOb_strptime.h and LibOb_strptime.c).

The only 'cost' are additional pointer parameters to transfer time zone and language data, but they all can be set to 0 in case just the conventional functionality is sufficient. The functions intentionally do not use the system 'locale', which is explained in the documentation.

For C++ programmers the class [cTime](https://github.com/OlafSimon/cTime) strongly related to this 'strptime' implementaion might be of interest.

Comment: MSVC supports C++20 chrono which has `std::chrono::parse`.   This is a superset of the `stptime` functionality.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35149032)

Answer (score -1):

One alternative is to use `GetSystemTime` and send the time information to a function that parses it according to your format using `vsnprintf_s`. In the
example below there is one function that creates a time string with milli second
precision. It then sends the string to a function that formats it according to the desired format:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <atlstr.h> 

std::string FormatToISO8601 (const std::string FmtS, ...) {
   CStringA BufferString;
   try {
       va_list VaList;
       va_start (VaList, FmtS);
       BufferString.FormatV (FmtS.c_str(), VaList);
   } catch (...) {}
   return std::string (BufferString);
}

void CreateISO8601String () {
   SYSTEMTIME st;
   GetSystemTime(&st);
   std::string MyISO8601String = FormatToISO8601 ("%4u-%02u-%02uT%02u:%02u:%02u.%03u", st.wYear, st.wMonth, st.wDay, st.wHour, st.wMinute, st.wSecond, st.wMilliseconds);
}
```

Comment: You've got things backwards. The question is asking for a way to convert a **string representation** into a `struct tm`, while you have presented a (poor) implementation of [strftime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe06s4ak.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

There is a version of strptime() for windows available at https://github.com/p-j-miller/date-time . The same location includes a matching strftime() function and a comprehensive test program. This also works under Linux if you need to create code that works on both OS's.