# C convert char[] to timestamp;

Tags: c++, timestamp, char

I have  char date[] = "2011-04-01"; How it convert to timestamp in C or C++ ?

Comment: Maybe this answer can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002542/how-to-convert-datetime-to-unix-timestamp-in-c

Comment: Your title says C, your question says C or C++, and you tagged just C++. Are you programming in C, or programming in C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
char date[] = "2011-04-01";
date[4] = date[7] = '\0';
struct tm tmdate = {0};
tmdate.tm_year = atoi(&date[0]) - 1900;
tmdate.tm_mon = atoi(&date[5]) - 1;
tmdate.tm_mday = atoi(&date[8]);
time_t t = mktime( &tmdate );
```

Comment: Note that this solutions assume that `"2011-04-01"` is the _local_ date and the DST is _not_ in effect as `tmdate.tm_mday == 0`.  Thus `time_t t` may be 1 hour off from midnight.

Answer (score 7):

Warning: **[strptime](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html)** is a [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)-function (may not be available through **time.h** on OS "Windows" platform).

```
#include <time.h>

struct tm time;
strptime("2011-04-01", "%Y-%m-%d", &time);
time_t loctime = mktime(&time);  // timestamp in current timezone
time_t gmttime = timegm(&time);  // timestamp in GMT
```

Comment: Not fully initializing/assigning   `time` can be a problem: "unspecified ... will update the current contents of the structure or overwrite all contents of the structure".  Suggest `struct tm time = {0};` and use `time->isdst == -1;`.

Comment: Where is it neccesary to use: "time->isdst == -1;"   ?