# How to convert date time from server to unix timestamp?

Tags: c, datetime, time, unix-timestamp

I need to understand how to convert a date/time (obtained from a server) to a UNIX timestamp.  I will be coding in C.  Any ideas on how this might be done, or perhaps someone guide me to similar existing code?

Comment: You need to be more specific about what server you are talking about.

Comment: From where do you get your DATE TIME and in which format? Your question is being downvoted for lack of clarity. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002542/how-to-convert-datetime-to-unix-timestamp-in-c

Answer (score -1):

See the db_unix_timestamp() function found here: 
http://svn.cubrid.org/cubridengine/trunk/src/query/string_opfunc.c

---

Here is a way that might work for you:

```
{
char *dateTimeString =  "2014-05-10 15:50:49"; //"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"
struct tm t;
time_t t_of_day;
char *cp = dateTimeString;


t.tm_year  = strtol(cp, &cp, 10);      // 2011-1900;
t.tm_mon   = strtol(++cp, &cp, 10);    // Month, 0 - jan
t.tm_mday  = strtol(++cp, &cp, 10);    // Day of the month
t.tm_hour  = strtol(++cp, &cp, 10);
t.tm_min   = strtol(++cp, &cp, 10);
t.tm_sec   = strtol(++cp, &cp, 10);
t.tm_isdst = -1;                       // Is DST on? 1 = yes, 0 = no, -1 = unknown

t_of_day = mktime(&t);
printf("seconds since the Epoch: %ld\n", (long) t_of_day)
}
```

Comment: The date and time format will be in string "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS", and unix timestamp has to handle leap years also. How has to be done this?

Comment: @Sujatha,  There are many ways to parse the string "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" into it's individual numerical components.  I modified the answer to show a way to do it using 'strtol()'; but you might also consider other string parsing methods, such as 'sscanf()', etc.

Comment: @Sujatha, as far as leap year goes, the 'mktime()' function includes leap-year in it's conversion to UNIX timestamp.  If you want to know how 'mktime()' works, you might consider asking that in a new/separate question.

Comment: This approach would only work if the server returns a time in the same time zone as you, which, all things being considered, is probably unlikely. `strptime()` is also a much more elegant way of doing this than parsing it manually. It's POSIX-only, rather than ISO C, but then so is assuming `mktime()` returns "seconds since the Epoch", and assuming that `time_t` is an integral type. You're also not interpreting the `tm_year` and `tm_mon` members correctly, even though the comments suggest you know you should be.