# How to convert a date time string to long (UNIX Epoch Time) in Java 8 (Scala)

Tags: java, scala, datetime, java-8, epoch

I want the UNIX Epoch Time (Posix Time, Unix Time) of a string in some `pattern`, the string is in normal format (so UTC).  Please using Java 8, not Joda or old Java.

(For milliseconds please see [How to convert a date time string to long (UNIX Epoch Time) Milliseconds in Java 8 (Scala)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55124653/how-to-convert-a-date-time-string-to-long-unix-epoch-time-milliseconds-in-java))

So far I have the below, but I hate this for a number of reasons:

1. It's way too verbose for what is the most common thing to do with dates (convert to UNIX Epoch Time).  7 method calls for what should be 1.
2. It has to specify UTC, but surely UTC is just a default, why do I have to be explicit here?
3. It has a string literal `"UTC"`
4. It has a magic number `ZoneOffset.ofHours(0)`

My best so far:

```
def dateTimeStringToEpoch(s: String, pattern: String): Long = 
    LocalDateTime.parse(s, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern))
      .atZone(ZoneId.ofOffset("UTC", ZoneOffset.ofHours(0)))
      .toInstant().getEpochSeconds
```

Also, bonus question, is it efficient? Is there any overhead to creating the `DateTimeFormatter` via `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern)`? If so why?

Comment: At least there is a UTC constant [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC)

Comment: What input looks like?

Comment: "It's way too verbose": this is why subroutines (aka functions or methods) have been invented very early in the history of computers.

Comment: Yes, there is probably an overhead from creating the `DateTimeFormatter` each time. If worried and the pattern is the same, make it a constant. You can safely do that, it is thread-safe. One method call less for each invocation…

Comment: I would have thought this question to be a duplicate (for example of [Convert a date format in epoch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687433/convert-a-date-format-in-epoch)), but even though I would never use a count of method calls as a metric for code quality, there are some very interesting points coming up in the answers.

Comment: Most languages you can do it in 2 or less calls (one to parse to some struct, one to convert struct to unix time).  In Unix C programming you can do it in 2, and C should really set the standard https://stackoverflow.com/a/1002631/1586965

Comment: It’s good that we don’t have to agree, @samthebest

Comment: @OleV.V. Count of native method calls is not THE metric, but it is useful.  Suppose instead, it was 1000 method calls, you could, by that information alone, know that the code must be unnecessarily complex right?

Comment: *"what is the most common thing to do with dates (convert to UNIX Epoch Time)."* Really? I've written lots of code with dates, and I've never had to convert a date to UNIX Epoch Time. By far the *most common thing* I've done with dates is formatting them for display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is more than two times shorter (**only 3 method calls**):

```
def dateTimeStringToEpoch(s: String, pattern: String): Long = 
     LocalDateTime.parse(s, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern))
                  .toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC)
```

Btw, I would build the `DateTimeFormatter` outside of `dateTimeStringToEpoch` and pass it as a method parameter:

```
def dateTimeStringToEpoch(s: String, formatter: DateTimeFormatter): Long = 
     LocalDateTime.parse(s, formatter).toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC)
```

Having actually run a performance test, there is little difference in performance (barely a factor of 2) in initialising the `DateTimeFormatter` outside the method.

```
scala> val pattern = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
pattern: String = yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss

scala>   time(() => randomDates.map(dateTimeStringToEpoch(_, pattern)))
Took: 1216

scala>   time(() => randomDates.map(dateTimeStringToEpochFixed))
Took: 732
```

Comment: There isn't a `.toEpochMilli` method here :(

Comment: Libraries required for this solution: import java.time.{LocalDateTime, ZoneOffset}
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

Answer (score 3):

You may use the equivalent of the following Java code:

```
static long dateTimeStringToEpoch(String s, String pattern) {
    return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern).withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)
        .parse(s, p -> p.getLong(ChronoField.INSTANT_SECONDS));
}
```

Of course, processing `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern).withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)` implies work that could be avoided when encountering the same pattern string multiple times. Whether this amount of work is relevant for your application, depends on what is is doing beside this operation.

Comment: Very nice! 4 method calls instead of 7 (and I disagree with the asker that it ought to be 1; there are a number of things we want to specify explicitly in the conversion).

Comment: @OleV.V. …and the result of `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern).withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)` could be reused, so the actual operation is the sole `parse` call, returning the desired value rather than something that needs to get converted.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this one, based on what you have said, it is parsing UTC time, so I have this as a sample.

`Instant.parse("2019-01-24T12:48:14.530Z").getEpochSecond`