# How to convert a date time string to long (UNIX Epoch Time) Milliseconds in Java 8 (Scala)

Tags: java, scala, datetime, java-8, epoch

This question solves the case for seconds: [How to convert a date time string to long (UNIX Epoch Time) in Java 8 (Scala)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54346584/how-to-convert-a-date-time-string-to-long-unix-epoch-time-in-java-8-scala/54347244#54347244)

But if I want milliseconds it seems I have to use

```
def dateTimeStringToEpoch(s: String, pattern: String): Long = 
    LocalDateTime.parse(s, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern))
      .atZone(ZoneId.ofOffset("UTC", ZoneOffset.ofHours(0)))
      .toInstant().toEpochMilli
```

which is ugly for the 4 issues I detail in the other question (main things I don't like is the magic literal `"UTC"` and the magic number `0`).

Unfortunately the following does not compile

```
def dateTimeStringToEpoch(s: String, pattern: String): Long = 
     LocalDateTime.parse(s, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern))
                  .toEpochMilliSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC)
```

as `toEpochMilliSecond` does not exist

Comment: Replace `ZoneId.ofOffset("UTC", ZoneOffset.ofHours(0))` with [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC)

Comment: @Andreas almost. ZoneOffset.UTC is a `ZoneOffset`, so need to change the call to `atZone` to be `atOffset`.

Comment: @ptomli Not strictly needed since a `ZoneOffset` is a `ZoneId`. The difference is whether you get a `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime` back, but since both have the `toInstant()` method, and the object is not otherwise used, it makes no difference.

Comment: @Andreas And StackOverflow teaches me something new, yet again... Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you not use [LocalDateTime#atOffset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC) and [ZoneOffset#UTC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC)?

```
LocalDateTime.parse(s, dateTimeFormatter).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant().toEpochMilli()
```

As @Andreas points out in the comments, `ZoneOffset` is-a `ZoneId`, so you could use

```
def dateTimeStringToEpoch(s: String, pattern: String): Long = 
    LocalDateTime.parse(s, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern))
      .atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)
      .toInstant()
      .toEpochMilli()
```

Answer (score 2):

When working with UNIX Epoch, I suggest using `java.time.Instant` as it designed for epoch representation and takes `UTC` into consideration by default, as it is part of the standard.

```
import java.time.Instant

object InstantFormat extends App {

  //Instant.parse uses DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT
  println(Instant.parse("2019-03-12T15:15:13.147Z"))
  println(Instant.parse("2019-03-12T15:15:13Z"))
  println(Instant.parse("2019-03-12T15:15:13Z").toEpochMilli)
  println(Instant.parse("2019-03-12T15:15:13Z").getEpochSecond)
  println(Instant.ofEpochMilli(1552403713147L))
  println(Instant.ofEpochSecond(1552403713L))
}
```

outputs

```
2019-03-12T15:15:13.147Z
2019-03-12T15:15:13Z
1552403713000
1552403713
2019-03-12T15:15:13.147Z
2019-03-12T15:15:13Z
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54347537/2711488) to return epoch millis like

```
static long dateTimeStringToEpoch(String s, String pattern) {
    return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern).withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)
        .parse(s, Instant::from).toEpochMilli();
}
```

Or, if you even want to avoid the construction of a temporary `Instant`:

```
static long dateTimeStringToEpoch(String s, String pattern) {
    return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern).withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)
        .parse(s, ta -> ta.getLong(ChronoField.INSTANT_SECONDS)*1000
                       +ta.get(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND));
}
```

Note that both, `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern).withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)` and `ta -> ta.getLong(ChronoField.INSTANT_SECONDS)*1000+ta.get(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND)` are reusable components here, e.g. you could do

```
static final DateTimeFormatter MY_PATTERN
    = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
static final TemporalQuery<Long> EPOCH_MILLIS
    = ta -> ta.getLong(ChronoField.INSTANT_SECONDS)*1000+ta.get(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND);
```

and

```
long millis = MY_PATTERN.parse("2018-07-21 18:30", EPOCH_MILLIS);
```

The question is, how many different format strings do you expect to occur within you application. Usually, it’s not something that changes as often as the formatted dates you have to parse. It might be beneficial to create a cache mapping from format string to prepared `DateTimeFormatter`. The lambda expression is a singleton anyway.

Comment: I can't seem to get that to compile in Scala, not sure how to translate `Instant::from`

Comment: `Instant::from` is equivalent to `ta -> Instant.from(ta)` or `(TemporalAccessor ta) -> Instant.from(ta)`. It’s a function invoking the `static` method [`Instant.from(TemporalAccessor)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#from-java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor-). On the Java side, this function will implement `TemporalQuery<Instant>` but that’s determined by type inference.

Comment: Because I'm using an old (2.11) version of Scala I think I'm having issues, so I have to do it the long way like this: `.parse(s, new TemporalQuery[Instant] {override def queryFrom(temporal: TemporalAccessor): Instant = Instant.from(temporal)})`