# How can I parse a strftime formatted string in Perl?

Tags: perl, datetime

I am new to Perl and I wan to know whether there is an inverse function to the strftime().
Look,

```
use POSIX qw(strftime);
print strftime("%YT%mT%d TTTT%H:%M:%S", localtime)
```

I get: 2009T08T14 TTTT00:37:02. How can I do the oposite operation? From "2009T08T14 TTTT00:37:02" string to get 2009-08-14 00:37:02, knowing the formatting string "%YT%mT%d TTTT%H:%M:%S"?

Comment: Wait, I answered too quickly. Do you mean, you want the string **`2009-08-14 00:37:02`** or the number of seconds since the epoch?

Comment: I want to get the time from the string 2009T08T14 TTTT00:37:02 in order to compare it with "valid" timestamps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option is to parse the numbers using a regular expression and then use [Time::Local](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Time::Local). However, now that I understand your question is how to go from a `strftime` formatted string to a time in general, that approach is bound to be cumbersome.

You mention in your answer `POSIX::strptime` which is great if your platform supports it. Alternatively, you can use [DateTime::Format::Strptime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DateTime::Format::Strptime):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $f = "%YT%mT%d TTTT%H:%M:%S";
my $s = strftime($f, localtime);

print "$s\n";

my $Strp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
    pattern   => $f,
    locale    => 'en_US',
    time_zone => 'US/Eastern',
);

my $dt = $Strp->parse_datetime($s);

print $dt->epoch, "\n";
print scalar localtime $dt->epoch, "\n";
```

`$dt` is a [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DateTime) object so you can do pretty much whatever you want with it.

Comment: Ok, but whaat if I have a function whose parameter is the formatting string (here for ex. "%YT%mT%d TTTT%H:%M:%S")  but I do not know it exactly..So, I am looking for the oposite of the strftime function
.

Comment: No, just use DateTime::Format::Strptime instead.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have found the solution: `strptime($strptime_pattern, $string)`

Comment: I did not know about http://search.cpan.org/dist/POSIX-strptime/ ... However, it looks like I cannot install that on Windows because `strptime` does not exist on Windows. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321849/strptime-equivalent-on-windows for more information.

Comment: Of course, you may not care about Windows. I am just mentioning it in case you are concerned about portability.

Answer (score 0):

So easyy

```
use Time::ParseDate;
my $t = '2009T08T14 TTTT00:37:02';

$t =~ s/TTTT//;
$t =~ s/T/-/g;

$seconds_since_jan1_1970 = parsedate($t)
```