# Compare date intervals in strftime format 

Tags: perl, bash, strftime

I have multiple input files with dates in `strftime format`.The date format is one of input variables. I need to decide if their timeline is continuous; in another words, if dates intervals of all input files don't overlap.

The data in files are continuous. It's like one file is one interval. First date in the file is left side of interval and last date is right side of the interval.

To better demonstrate my problem ( Just an example with data format %Y.%m.%d %H:%M ):

Have 2 data files, where date format is %Y.%m.%d %H:%M

data1.txt

```
2012.11.20 17:10 134343
2012.11.21 00:10 13323343
2012.12.22 15:10 13432323
```

data2.txt

```
2012.10.20 17:10 134343
2012.11.29 00:10 13333223343
2012.11.30 15:10 134323123
```

So, as you can see dates in files data1.txt and data2.txt overlap.

```
       2012.10.20         2012.11.20           2012.11.30                2012.12.22
```

`data2.txt <=============================================>`

```
                   data1.txt <===================================================>
```

I am implementing this issue in bash, but I welcome some Perl fragments too.

I can't find any simple solution.

Thanks!

Comment: I have already tried with perl Time::Piece->strptime , but only to filter valid date formats

Comment: It is far from clear from your data what constitutes an *interval*. Do you need to check that there are no gaps in the set of intervals, or just that there are no overlaps?

Comment: data inside each files are continuous. Like one file is one interval
First date in File is left side of interval adn last date is right side of the interval

Comment: As you said "input files dont'overlap" , this means you just want "unique files + maintianing the time interval (sort)" from a given list....??

Comment: Nope, you see i have to plot these data. And i have to decide if i generate one plot or multiplot. So i need to know what timebases have my input files. Hope it's clear

Comment: data1.txt,data2.txt and then sample data again....It's confusing...Kindly reformat your question !!

Comment: It is already answered here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274800/how-can-i-parse-a-strftime-formatted-string-in-perl

Comment: @ceving Please, read again my whole question. My problem is mainly about interval arthmetic with dates in strftime format.

Comment: @Rob: please stop writing *strftime format* as it is meaningless. You must explain what you mean.

Comment: The two intervals [t0; t1[ and [s0; s1[ do not overlap if s1 < t0 or s0 > t1.

Comment: @ceving Please, can you explain yourself ?

Comment: An interval [t0; t1[ includes t0 and excludes t1. t0 and t1 are two time stamps. For details see chapter 4 in Developing Time-Oriented Database Applications in SQL http://www.cs.arizona.edu/people/rts/tdbbook.pdf

Comment: By "strftime format" I think he means a time string that can be produced by `strftime` (and thus can be parsed by `strptime`).

Comment: @Dennis Williamson By "strftime format" i mean this [strftime(3c)](http://static.cray-cyber.org/Documentation/NEC_SX_R10_1/G1AB02E/STRFTIME.3C.HTML)

Comment: I'm quite familiar with `strftime`. Your terminology is imprecise. I think the clarification in my comment is an improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculating the overlap of ranges of data is no trivial task, especially when dealing with date/time values.

I suggest the [`Time::Piece::Range`](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aPiece%3a%3aRange) module. It extends the core `Time::Piece` module to handle ranges of dates, and has an `overlap` method.

The code below implements a function `range_from_file` which, when supplied with the name of a file, reads a date from all records that contain one and creates an array of `Time::Piece` objects. The array is sorted and a `Time::Piece::Range` object is formed from the first and last elements of the sorted list and returned.

Calling this subroutine on the two data files produces two `Time::Piece::Range` objects, and a final call of the `overlap` method determines whether the two files encompass duplicate date/times.

When applied to your sample files `data1.txt` and `data2.txt` this code confirms that they overlap.

Note that although `Time::Piece` is now a core module, `Time::Piece::Range` is not, and it also requires non-core modules `Date::Range` and `Date::Simple` to be installed. The `cpan` utility will install dependencies automatically for you, but this may be a problem if you don't have authority to augment your Perl installation.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece::Range;

sub range_from_file {

  my $file = shift;
  open my $fh, '<', $file or die qq(Unable to open "$file" for reading);

  my @dates;
  while (<$fh>) {
    next unless /(\d+\.\d+\.\d+[ ]\d+:\d+)/;
    push @dates, Time::Piece->strptime($1, '%Y.%m.%d %H:%M');
  }

  return Time::Piece::Range->new((sort {$a <=> $b} @dates)[0,-1]);
}

my $r1 = range_from_file('data1.txt');
my $r2 = range_from_file('data2.txt');

print $r1->overlaps($r2) ? 'overlap' : 'distinct';
```

---

**Update**

Given that you are unable to use anything but core modules, and that you are assuming that the `strftime` format contains nothing but fixed-length fields (such as `%B`) I suggest this alternative.

I have modified the `range_from_file` to take an additional `$format` parameter which is the `strftime` format to be used to decode the data.

The length of the initial date/time field of each record is established by formatting the current date/time with the supplied format and finding the length of the resulting string.

The equivalent number of characters is extracted from the start of each file record, and the first and last dates in the file are stored in the array `@dates`.

The two dates are converted to `Time::Piece` objects, and returned as the *range* of the file in an anonymous array.

A new subroutine `overlap` checks whether two ranges overlap. They are separate if the end of the first falls before the beginngin of the second, or the end of the second before the beginning of the first. Otherwise they overlap.

Again, this code confirms that your sample data in files `data1.txt` and `data2.txt` overlap.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece 'localtime';

sub range_from_file {

  my ($file, $format) = @_;
  open my $fh, '<', $file or die qq(Unable to open "$file" for reading);

  my $size = length Time::Piece->new->strftime($format);

  my @dates;
  while (<$fh>) {
    pop @dates if @dates >= 2;
    push @dates, substr $_, 0, $size;
  }

  my @range = map Time::Piece->strptime($_, $format), @dates;
  return \@range;
}

sub overlap {
  my ($r1, $r2) = @_;
  return not $r1->[1] < $r2->[0] or $r2->[1] < $r1->[0];
}

my $r1 = range_from_file('data1.txt', '%Y.%m.%d %H:%M');
my $r2 = range_from_file('data2.txt', '%Y.%m.%d %H:%M');

print overlap($r1, $r2) ? 'overlap' : 'distinct';
```

Comment: The date format is not fixed, but it is variable in strftime format.
But, in my case it doesnt matter cause all lines in file are valid (next unless /(\d+\.\d+\.\d+[ ]\d+:\d+)/;
 is not necessary) I am not unforutnatelly sure if i can use uncore modules.

Comment: I think you only need to look at the first and last lines of the files rather than every line.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: the sample data appears to be sorted, but the OP hasn't confirmed that it is so we cannot assume it.

Comment: From the question: "First date in the file is left side of interval and last date is right side of the interval."

Comment: @Rob: what do you mean by *the date format is not fixed*? All your date/times in the sample data have the same format; is that not representative? *strftime format* doesn't mean anything as `strftime` creates a date/time string according to a format specifier which can be anything. The line `next unless /(\d+\.\d+\.\d+[ ]\d+:\d+)/` *is* necessary as it captures the date/time substring of the record for further processing. Please try not to drip-feed information like this. If you clarify this date format issue and confirm that you cannot install modules I will try to write a different solution.

Comment: @Dennis: I couldn't make head nor tail of what that sentence meant by *left side* and *right side*! I see now. Thanks.

Comment: @Borodin Ok. I write bash script, which is processing files and plots graphs. User will provide `date format` and `data input files`. Provided `date format` and `dates in data input file` have to match. I've already taken care of this issue. So that's why i wrote that date format is not fixed. The input files contain only valid data. And i cannot use the module. It's not on target mashine (cannot add it)

Comment: @Rob: so in parsing the data from your files, how can we know where the date/time string in each record ends and the supplementary data - `134343` etc. - ends? And what do you mean in your question when you say *Have 2 data files, where date format is %Y.%m.%d %H:%M*? Is this simply untrue?

Comment: @Borodin It was meant only as example. The length of specific date in strftime date format is fixed. Try to expand specific strftime date format and you get always same length. So that's i wrote that date is in strftime data format.

Comment: @Rob: You will need to use `strptime` with the format provided by the user to parse the input dates.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson Thank you for suggestion, but as i already mentioned, i have solved parsing the input date.

Comment: @Rob: OK I think I know enough to try once more. You keep saying you have *solved parsing the input date* but you don't say what that means or show your code so I don't see how I can use that information. I have updated my answer to do what I now think you want.

Comment: @Borodin Yes, that's the right way. Sorry, if description was litle confusing, my first post and in haste :) Again, thank you

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you need to compare dates (with or without times?) that have been converted to a lexically comparable format. That means that the dates are consistently `YYYY.MM.DD` (with leading zeros if necessary.

```
#!/bin/bash
file1=$1
file2=$2
read -r start1 end1 < <(awk 'NR == 1 {print "$1-$2"} END {print "$1-$2"}' "$file1")
read -r start2 end2 < <(awk 'NR == 1 {print "$1-$2"} END {print "$1-$2"}' "$file2")
if [[ $start1 > $start2 || $end1 > $start2 ]]
then
    echo "Overlap!"
fi
```

Comment: The assumption "That means that the dates are consistently YYYY.MM.DD" is not true. I have alredy tried also in nawk, but it doesn't have any equivalentfunction to strptime () like perl. And in addition the interval aritmetic would be at least problematic, because you wouldnt know where's the most significant value, the second and so on ...

Comment: @Rob: I thought you already had the date parsing solved!!?!? What do you mean you wouldn't know where the most significant value is?

Answer (score -1):

Do it with perl.

If the two files cont. then the dates overlap only if the date in the last line of file1 is earlier than the first line of file2 you are ok.

1) get first line
2) parse line
my ($date1,$data) = line (/\t/,$line);
or you Text:Csv
3) parse date1 and date2
my ($Y1,$m1,$d1,$H1,$M1) = $date =~ m!(\d\d\d\d).(\d\d).(\d\d)\s+(\d\d):(\d\d)!gis;
4) create epoch 
use DateTime;

$dt1 = DateTime->new(
      year       => $Y1,
      month      => $m1,
      day        => $d1,
      hour       => $h1,
      minute     => $m1,
      second     => 0,
      nanosecond => 0,
      time_zone  => 'UTC',
  );
my $epoch1 = $dt1->epoch;
my $epoch2 = $dt2->epoch;

5) if epoch1 smaller than epoch2 you are good.

Comment: The date format is not fixed, but it is variable in strftime format.

Comment: This is a dreadful answer. It is both wrong and barely readable.