# Any gotchas for Activestate Perl versus POSIX perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have a script that relies on the DateTime module.
As part of my move to integrate my development into one environment, I've changed from command line in linux and cygwin to Eclipse on Windows 7.

In linux/cygwin the following line:

```
$time_value = strftime "%F %H:%M:%S %p", localtime;
```

produces the time data:

```
2013-07-24 13:46:19
```

But from Eclipse, in an Activestate PERL environment (all pertinent modules installed)
I get:

```
%F %H:%M:%S %p
```

The strange thing is that it's the exact same script file. I'm using the DateTime module which is installed in both environments, but this output suggests the module is failing.

Any thoughts from knowledgeable PERL gurus?

UPDATE:

I'm using POSIX qw(strftime) as suggested in this answer:
[How can I parse a strftime formatted string in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274800/how-can-i-parse-a-strftime-formatted-string-in-perl)

My goal is to convert dates in this format:
    Wed, 07 Aug 2010 18:22:30 -0600

Into any of a number of MySQL date_format forms.

So if POSIX makes the program unportable, what are my options?

Comment: strftime is from POSIX module, localtime is a standard Perl function.

Comment: May we ass-u-me that you've already studied [`perlport`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlport)?

Comment: I am not familiar with perlport.
I am teaching myself by trying out little projects, so any suggestions or tips on resources would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `strftime` function you are using is not from the DateTime module. That module is purely object oriented, and uses methods: `$dt->strftime($format)`.

It seems that you have imported the [`strftime` from the POSIX module](https://metacpan.org/module/RJBS/perl-5.18.0/ext/POSIX/lib/POSIX.pod#strftime). For the function in question, some limits on portability are made:

> […] Consult your system's "`strftime()`" manpage for details about these and the other arguments.
>
> If you want your code to be portable, your format ("fmt") argument should use only the conversion specifiers defined by the ANSI C standard (C89, to play safe).  These are `"aAbBcdHIjmMpSUwWxXyYZ%"`.  But even then, the results of some of the conversion specifiers are non-portable.

You see that `%F` is not among these portable format specifiers.

Comment: Thanks. That helps.
Time to understand perlport I guess.
I'd like to write portable code as a fundamental way of doing this.

Comment: It's not particularly clear from the answer above: remove POSIX and just use DateTime to write portable code.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change %F to %Y-%m-%d.