# R switches from PDT to PST at 1:36:14 and not at 2:00:00 - Lubridate assigns time zone before switch

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

When looking at date-time values overlapping the timezone change from PDT to PST, it seems like R switches timezones at 1:36:14 and not at 2:00:00 as expected. Specifically, R assigns PST timezones to all date-times after 2021-11-07 01:36:14 (as shown below):

```
x <-c(
    "2021-11-07 1:00:00",
    "2021-11-07 1:00:01",
    "2021-11-07 1:35:00",
    "2021-11-07 1:36:00",
    "2021-11-07 1:36:10",
    "2021-11-07 1:36:14",
    "2021-11-07 1:36:15",
    "2021-11-07 1:36:30",
    "2021-11-07 1:36:59",
    "2021-11-07 1:45:00",
    "2021-11-07 1:59:59",
    "2021-11-07 2:00:00",
    "2021-11-07 2:30:00"
    )
x_pst <- as.POSIXct(x, tz = "PST8PDT")
> x_pst
# ...
[5] "2021-11-07 01:36:10 PDT" "2021-11-07 01:36:14 PDT"
[7] "2021-11-07 01:36:15 PST" "2021-11-07 01:36:30 PST"
# ...
```

To add on to this, lubridate seemingly adjusts all date-times to PST before the switch (using the same data):

```
x_pst <- lubridate::as_datetime(x, tz = "PST8PDT")
> x_pst
[1] "2021-11-07 01:00:00 PST" "2021-11-07 01:00:01 PST"
[3] "2021-11-07 01:35:00 PST" "2021-11-07 01:36:00 PST"
[5] "2021-11-07 01:36:10 PST" "2021-11-07 01:36:14 PST"
[7] "2021-11-07 01:36:15 PST" "2021-11-07 01:36:30 PST"
[9] "2021-11-07 01:36:59 PST" "2021-11-07 01:45:00 PST"
[11] "2021-11-07 01:59:59 PST" "2021-11-07 02:00:00 PST"
[13] "2021-11-07 02:30:00 PST"

x_pst <- lubridate::ymd_hms(x, tz = "PST8PDT")
> x_pst
# same output as above
```

So why the timezone switch at such a specific time, and also what is lubridate doing by assigning the PST to all date times before the change?

Session Information:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sonoma 14.0

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib 
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib;  LAPACK version 3.11.0

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

time zone: US/Pacific
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.3.1   generics_0.1.3   tools_4.3.1     
[4] lubridate_1.9.3  timechange_0.2.0
```

Comment: I can replicate this, and going back to at least R 3.6. I can also get the same results with "US/Pacific"

Comment: Hmm. On my system `all(sapply(as.POSIXlt(x_pst), \(x) x$zone) == "PST")` is TRUE for the first example. (Pop!_OS 22.04, time locale is `en_CA.UTF-8`, local time zone is America/Toronto). Can you edit your question to include the results of `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: @BenBolker - confirming that is definitely `FALSE` for me on R 4.3.1 Windows 10. tzcode source: internal.

Comment: FWIW I have "tzcode source: system (glibc)", using R-devel

Comment: I don’t think lubridate is the cause, since you see it with as.POSIXct. I can confirm this behavior on a Mac running 4.2.3.

Comment: @BenBolker - sessionInfo() added!

Comment: I think the answer comes down to this function [guess_offset](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/cf73cd12734254ba7c699ed9e3881afcd62e00e3/src/main/datetime.c#L404). If you look at the function `RApiDatetime::rapistrptime` we see that `isdst` is returning `TRUE` for all of the values that return `PDT` and 0 otherwise.

Comment: My initial guess was wrong. It looks like the culprit is the `C` function `mktime`. If you follow the rabbit hole you end up in [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5e8d34a554c58cbbdad120f1f113e939c1133a76/src/main/datetime.c#L546). Before this call, `tm->tm_isdst = -1` and afterwards is `tm->tm_isdst = 1` for "2021-11-07 1:36:14". For any time after that, `tm->tm_isdst` remains -1. This ends up causing the 3600 offset.

Comment: When I get some time, I intend on writing a pure `C` function to confirm this. If you read the documentation on `mktime` there doesn't appear to be any real indication as to why.

Comment: Probably a stupid comment, but whatever. Basically all the `x` timestamps are ambiguous since that day you have twice, say, the `01:35:10` timestamp. I don't think we can expect a specific interpretation from R; it simply looks like that after an arbitrary threshold, R chooses `PST` rather than `PDT`. Apparently `lubridate` chooses another mechanism to break the ambiguity, but I'd say that the root cause is not what R or lubridate are reporting, but the intrinsic ambiguity of your data.

Comment: @nicola, did you see my comment above? I built the code myself and debugged it. I think it boils down to `mktime` from `C`. I’m not at a computer right now, but I intend to show this.

Comment: @JosephWood I saw your comments, but I don't think we can define this as a bug. From the OP: *R switches timezones at 1:36:14 and not at 2:00:00 as expected*: I don't understand why we should expect 02:00:00 more than any other random point between 01:00:00 and 02:00:00.

Comment: I would imagine this had to do with an empiric distribution of latency, on best knowledge at the time of code writing, where a large network would converge at `ting` 2:00. This requires tossing the clock on the wall time, and interestingly, highly regularized system time,in favor of the empiric latencies, by where one's computer was (say, on the early internet). Latency also effects reporting. If every box is supposed to report at `ting` with money and confidence riding on it, oh, and you're writing the code, account for latency. The centralized topology of reporting isn't much discussed.

Answer (score 7):

This is not a complete answer, but I hope someone with more expertise can build off this.

### `as.POSIXct`

Before I jump into the code, I first want to give some context. We start with the generic function `as.POSIXct` which has multiple `S3` methods defined.

```r
as.POSIXct
#> function (x, tz = "", ...)
#> UseMethod("as.POSIXct")

methods(as.POSIXct)
#> [1] as.POSIXct.Date    as.POSIXct.default as.POSIXct.numeric as.POSIXct.POSIXlt
#> see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
```

For the example given by the OP, since we are dealing with character data type, we will be using the `default` method:

```r
as.POSIXct.default
#> function (x, tz = "", ...)
#> {
#>     if (inherits(x, "POSIXct"))
#>         return(if (missing(tz)) x else .POSIXct(x, tz))
#>     if (is.null(x))
#>         return(.POSIXct(numeric(), tz))
#>     if (is.character(x) || is.factor(x))
#>         return(as.POSIXct(as.POSIXlt(x, tz, ...), tz, ...))
#>     if (is.logical(x) && all(is.na(x)))
#>         return(.POSIXct(as.numeric(x), tz))
#>     stop(gettextf("do not know how to convert '%s' to class %s",
#>         deparse1(substitute(x)), dQuote("POSIXct")), domain = NA)
#> }
```

This puts us calling `as.POSIXlt` (3rd condition above), a generic function which happens to have a character `S3` method: `as.POSIXlt.character`. I won't paste the source code, but the heart of the function is `strptime`.

```r
strptime
#> function (x, format, tz = "")
#> .Internal(strptime(if (is.character(x)) x else if (is.object(x)) `names<-`(as.character(x),
#>     names(x)) else `storage.mode<-`(x, "character"), format, tz))
```

You can see the `C` code [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/ac5687a7cc477d4461176013babe38ec4adfafeb/src/main/datetime.c#L1449C7-L1449C7). I initially tried logically following the code, however that proved to be very difficult.

### `RApiDatetime`

Fortunately, there is a package [RApiDatetime](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rapidatetime/tree/master) (thanks Dirk!) which has the function: `RApiDatetime::rapistrptime`. Calling it on the values provided by the OP we have:

```r
RApiDatetime::rapistrptime(x, fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", "PST8PDT")
#> $sec
#>  [1]  0  1  0  0 10 14 15 30 59  0 59  0  0
#>
#> $min
#>  [1]  0  0 35 36 36 36 36 36 36 45 59  0 30
#>
#> $hour
#>  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2
#>
#> $mday
#>  [1] 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
#>
#> $mon
#>  [1] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
#>
#> $year
#>  [1] 121 121 121 121 121 121 121 121 121 121 121 121 121
#>
#> $wday
#>  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#>
#> $yday
#>  [1] 310 310 310 310 310 310 310 310 310 310 310 310 310
#>
#> $isdst
#>  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#>
#> $zone
#>  [1] "PDT" "PDT" "PDT" "PDT" "PDT" "PDT" "PST" "PST" "PST" "PST" "PST" "PST" "PST"
#>
#> $gmtoff
#>  [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
#>
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"
#> attr(,"tzone")
#> [1] "PST8PDT" "PST"     "PDT"
```

We see the `isdst` field looks to be worth investigating. After cloning the repo and making crude usage of `printf`, I was more easily able to follow the path. We find that the real action behind `isdist` happens [here](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rapidatetime/blob/1a902fcfabf0b08c34a71aba68693ecc261b4ac5/src/datetime.c#L440).

```c
.
.
    OK = tm->tm_year < 138 && tm->tm_year >= (have_broken_mktime() ? 70 : 02);
    if(OK) {
    res = (double) mktime(tm);
    if (res == -1.) return res;
.
.
```

### `mktime`

Finally we get to my claim in the comments about `mktime`.

I wrote this very simple `C++` function to see what happens to our struct after a call to `mktime`:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void CheckMkTime(int tm_sec) {
    struct tm info;

    info.tm_sec = tm_sec;
    info.tm_min = 36;
    info.tm_hour = 1;
    info.tm_mday = 7;
    info.tm_mon = 10;
    info.tm_year = 121;
    info.tm_wday = 0;
    info.tm_yday = 310;
    info.tm_isdst = -1;

    time_t val = mktime(&info);
    printf("mktime_res: %jd,\n tm_zone: %s,\n tm_gmtoff: %ld,\n tm_sec: %d,\n "
           "tm_min: %d,\n tm_hour: %d,\n tm_mday: %d,\n tm_mon: %d,\n "
           "tm_year: %d,\n tm_wday: %d,\n tm_yday: %d,\n tm_isdst: %d,\n",
           val,
           info.tm_zone,
           info.tm_gmtoff,
           info.tm_sec,
           info.tm_min,
           info.tm_hour,
           info.tm_mday,
           info.tm_mon,
           info.tm_year,
           info.tm_wday,
           info.tm_yday,
           info.tm_isdst);
}
```

And calling it with `tm_sec = 14` we have:

```r
CheckMkTime(14)
#> mktime_res: 1636274174,
#>  tm_zone: PDT,
#>  tm_gmtoff: -25200,
#>  tm_sec: 14,
#>  tm_min: 36,
#>  tm_hour: 1,
#>  tm_mday: 7,
#>  tm_mon: 10,
#>  tm_year: 121,
#>  tm_wday: 0,
#>  tm_yday: 310,
#>  tm_isdst: 1,
```

And with `tm_sec = 15` we see:

```r
CheckMkTime(15)
#> mktime_res: 1636277775,
#>  tm_zone: PST,
#>  tm_gmtoff: -28800,
#>  tm_sec: 15,
#>  tm_min: 36,
#>  tm_hour: 1,
#>  tm_mday: 7,
#>  tm_mon: 10,
#>  tm_year: 121,
#>  tm_wday: 0,
#>  tm_yday: 310,
#>  tm_isdst: 0,
```

> So the problem is `mktime` right?

I'm not so sure...

I wrote the pure `C` code:

```c
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    struct tm info;

    info.tm_sec = 14;
    info.tm_min = 36;
    info.tm_hour = 1;
    info.tm_mday = 7;
    info.tm_mon = 10;
    info.tm_year = 121;
    info.tm_wday = 0;
    info.tm_yday = 310;
    info.tm_isdst = -1;

    time_t val = mktime(&info);
    printf("mktime_res: %jd,\n tm_zone: %s,\n tm_gmtoff: %ld,\n tm_sec: %d,\n "
               "tm_min: %d,\n tm_hour: %d,\n tm_mday: %d,\n tm_mon: %d,\n "
               "tm_year: %d,\n tm_wday: %d,\n tm_yday: %d,\n tm_isdst: %d\n",
               val,
               info.tm_zone,
               info.tm_gmtoff,
               info.tm_sec,
               info.tm_min,
               info.tm_hour,
               info.tm_mday,
               info.tm_mon,
               info.tm_year,
               info.tm_wday,
               info.tm_yday,
               info.tm_isdst);


    struct tm info2;
    info2.tm_sec = 15;
    info2.tm_min = 36;
    info2.tm_hour = 1;
    info2.tm_mday = 7;
    info2.tm_mon = 10;
    info2.tm_year = 121;
    info2.tm_wday = 0;
    info2.tm_yday = 310;
    info2.tm_isdst = -1;

    val = mktime(&info2);
    printf("\n\nmktime_res: %jd,\n tm_zone: %s,\n tm_gmtoff: %ld,\n tm_sec: %d,\n "
               "tm_min: %d,\n tm_hour: %d,\n tm_mday: %d,\n tm_mon: %d,\n "
               "tm_year: %d,\n tm_wday: %d,\n tm_yday: %d,\n tm_isdst: %d\n",
               val,
               info2.tm_zone,
               info2.tm_gmtoff,
               info2.tm_sec,
               info2.tm_min,
               info2.tm_hour,
               info2.tm_mday,
               info2.tm_mon,
               info2.tm_year,
               info2.tm_wday,
               info2.tm_yday,
               info2.tm_isdst);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled it, and ran it in the terminal:

```
% clang time_shift.c -o time_shift
% ./time_shift
#> mktime_res: 1636266974,
#>  tm_zone: EST,
#>  tm_gmtoff: -18000,
#>  tm_sec: 14,
#>  tm_min: 36,
#>  tm_hour: 1,
#>  tm_mday: 7,
#>  tm_mon: 10,
#>  tm_year: 121,
#>  tm_wday: 0,
#>  tm_yday: 310,
#>  tm_isdst: 0
#>
#>
#> mktime_res: 1636266975,
#>  tm_zone: EST,
#>  tm_gmtoff: -18000,
#>  tm_sec: 15,
#>  tm_min: 36,
#>  tm_hour: 1,
#>  tm_mday: 7,
#>  tm_mon: 10,
#>  tm_year: 121,
#>  tm_wday: 0,
#>  tm_yday: 310,
#>  tm_isdst: 0
```

We don't see the issue here. However, we do notice that the `tm_zone` is `EST` in both cases whereas when we ran it `R` **after** running `RApiDatetime::rapistrptime(x, fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", "PST8PDT")`, we obtained `PST` for 14 and `PDT` for 15.

> With this, I reran the `R` examples in a fresh session and obtained the same results as we do in the pure `C` implementation.

We don't see this behavior in a fresh `R` session after calling `strptime` in base `R`.

I tried looking at [mktime](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/time/mktime.c) source code, but it is way beyond me.

### Session Info

```r
sessionInfo()
#> R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16)
#> Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
#> Running under: macOS Ventura 13.4.1
#>
#> Matrix products: default
#> BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
#> LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib;  LAPACK version 3.11.0
#>
#> locale:
#> [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
#>
#> time zone: PST8PDT
#> tzcode source: internal
#>
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
#>
#> other attached packages:
#> [1] RApiDatetime_0.0.8
#>
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#> [1] compiler_4.3.1 tools_4.3.1    Rcpp_1.0.11
```

Comment: Great! Is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558919/mktime-and-tm-isdst helpful?

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533322/mktime-and-tm-isdst-flag

Comment: Super helpful! I’m still confused why the pure C code didn’t give the same results. I don’t fully understand time locale, but I think this has something to do with it.

Comment: this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13804095/4408538 looks interesting as well

Comment: It looks like `mktime` behaviour is inconsistent with ambiguous dates; also here are some examples: https://www.cygwin.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17646. However, I don't think we can define this as a bug, both from the R or `mktime` side.