# How do I compare strings in C++?

Tags: c++

One of my team (a C++ developer) tells me that it is 'very complicated and messy' to compare two strings for equality, because they could each be of several different string types. I am stunned that in 2014 this might still be the case (in C#, VB.Net and most other langauges I am familiar with, comparing strings is a trivial step). Is there not a freely available library that handles this type of detail, so that two strings can easily be compared for equality without worrying about their string types?

Comment: What is your definition of string equality? Is it "all bytes are equal", is it "all glyphs are equal", is it something different?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare the string in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785386/how-to-compare-the-string-in-c)

Comment: [`std::string::operator==`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp)?

Comment: or what about [string::compare](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/)?

Comment: @duDE I disagree that it is a duplicate of *that* particular question. That question seems to be about a specific kind of string containing dates.

Comment: *"because they could each be of several different string types"* Historical reasons. Different libraries use different string types; legacy code uses some kind of C-string etc. Even if everyone agreed to use the same encoding, C++ Standard Library types are not fit for interfaces on all platforms, since their layout is not standardized.

Comment: add a utility method to convert these "other" string types to std strings, then you may use ::compare or ::operator==

Comment: What kind of strings are you having problems with?

Comment: To clarify: this is legacy code that has 'string' variables of varying types (char, bstr, etc). The task is to compare two such variables to see if they hold the same 'string'. ie two variables of different types may in their own way contain strings representing 'Fred' or maybe 'Joe', and I want to test if they have the same 'value' (even if they are encoded differently, or whatever). The actuall string types are a given, so I can't change them all to std::string or whatever.

Comment: "I am stunned that in 2014 this might still be the case" - it isn't. We've had `std::string` for decades. Use that for all your internal logic, and only convert to or from weird types when you need them to support a particular weird API.

Comment: "Use std::string for all your internal logic" Thanks, but that is converting a relatively small problem into a large problem - this is a large codebase that will require a lot of modification to do that.

Comment: @MikeSeymour and call a UTF-8 transformation function every time you need to call a WinAPI function ... ugh (not that I really have a better idea)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can I compare utf8 string such as persian words in c++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141417/how-can-i-compare-utf8-string-such-as-persian-words-in-c)

Comment: -1 because you want to ask, but don't want to use google...

Comment: Friend, I don't know who you are but you clearly have time to waste. I came to Stackoverflow because I want to ask the people that are most likely to know the answer, rather than wade through hundreds of pages which may or may not contain a reliable answer. Your comment basically suggests that Stackoverflow is redundant, which is an interest insight. Thanks to everyone else who helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't very well formulated, but I think you have an issue with different `UTF`s. So even same bytes may mean different things.

If this so, you need to have the same base, e.g. `UTF-8`, you didn't included platform, but it looks like Windows, so you could use [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to convert data.

Also there some others ways to do that if this doesn't suit your needs, [so use Google](https://www.google.lt/?gws_rd=cr&ei=9nbfU82PEcv4yQPx54DgBg#q=c%2B%2B%20convert%20to%20utf-8)

Comment: Sorry, I meant Windows (Visual C++ specifically). I purposely didn't use Google because I don't want to invite millions of targeted spam emails inviting me on a C++ course :-)