how to convert a datetime string to epoch in fortran
I've got timestamp data in a string, like this:
02/05/2024 00:21:45 (day/month/year)
I need to get its corresponding epoch (number of seconds since Jan 1 1970). I've not found anything on the internet, just for Bash & java... or maybe I've found something kind of esoteric that I've not understood

Start by defining your date string more precisely. I read your sample date as 2nd May 2024, but Americans would read it as 5th February 2024. Which is it?

You're right. I meant the European way, that is, 2nd May 2024

I'd probably ultimately call the standard C function mktime() to generate the final result, possibly combined with strptime()  (if on a POSIX system) to turn the string into something mktime likes

Have you searched for available libraries? https://wavebitscientific.github.io/datetime-fortran/

Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354100/date-time-difference-in-fortran  Quite a few answers here including a couple of one-liners to get the number of days.  Just multiply by 86400 to get the seconds
