# Convert string time to UNIX timestamp

Tags: c++, unix-timestamp

I have a string like `2013-05-29T21:19:48Z`. I'd like to convert it to the number of seconds since 1 January 1970 (the UNIX epoch), so that I can save it using just 4 bytes (or maybe 5 bytes, to avoid the year 2038 problem). How can I do that in a portable way? (My code has to run both on Linux and Windows.)

I can get the date parts out of the string, but I don't know how to figure out the number of seconds. I tried looking at the [documentation of date and time utilities in C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono), but I didn't find anything.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Rapptz See update. I tried looking at the documentation, but didn't find anything.

Comment: C++ doesn't have good date/time utilities like other languages such as C#. Your best bet is probably to find something in the [Boost libraries](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/) which are applicable to your situation.

Comment: Whether you're on Windows or Linux, an answer that mentions solutions for both (including boost) is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321849/strptime-equivalent-on-windows

Answer (score 8):

Here is the working code

```
string s{"2019-08-22T10:55:23.000Z"};
std::tm t{};
std::istringstream ss(s);

ss >> std::get_time(&t, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S");
if (ss.fail()) {
    throw std::runtime_error{"failed to parse time string"};
}   
std::time_t time_stamp = mktime(&t);
```

Answer (score 4):

use [std::get_time](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time) if you want the c++ way - but both other options are also valid. strptime will ignore the Z at the end - and the T can be accomodated by format string `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%s` - but you could also just put the Z at the end.

Comment: But that doesn't return UNIX timestamp.

Comment: Please consider making your answer more holistic, e.g. explaining about std::locale, facets and whether mktime  heads time zones or not, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`strptime()`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r12/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r12.bpxbd00/strptip.htm). For a Windows alternative, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321849/strptime-equivalent-on-windows).

Comment: especially if you can't use C++11 (where Iwan Aucamp's solution can be used)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [boost date_time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html) ore more specific `ptime`.

Use `ptime time_from_string(std::string)` to init your time and `long total_seconds()` to get the seconds of the duration.