# How to parse datetime from a file into a class in C++

Tags: c++, datetime

I am trying to parse a Class data from a txt file in C++. The Class data looks like this, contains some datetime string, some integer and some int.

The data in the txt file looks like this:

2014-08-01 02:06:53,3.9070,9

How to parse the data from the file into the Class?

Problems faced:
1) getting the input from the file for the datetime
2) separating the datetime input from the other data input.

Comment: If you're lucky you are on a system with a [`strptime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html) function. Otherwise there are [alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321849/strptime-equivalent-on-windows).

Comment: And you don't need the `!in.eof()` in your loop condition, it's redundant.

Comment: Or am I misunderstanding you? The way you read the date-time string from the file does not follow the format you give in the question at all. Instead you construct a string of that format and store in the class. My question is of course why you want to store a date-time stamp internally *as text*? You should read the data-time stamp as text, then parse it into a binary time-stamp than can be used by the C or C++ standard functions, preferably in a [C++11 `chrono` object](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono).

Comment: And considering that you store the data-time as a string in the structure, what does `Datetime::Parse` do? Parse from a string into a binary time-stamp, then convert that back into a string again?

Comment: As for the format in the file, please show a *complete* and *unmodified* record. Does it contain newlines? Is it comma-separated between fields? And what is the *actual* format for the date-time?

Comment: date-time format is locale dependend, that's the whole problem. If everyone used the same date-time - you will never get such a question. For example my date time is:

$ date
Пт авг 15 10:44:34 UZT 2014

Comment: how to find datetime format for my computer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have multiple problems, most of them regarding your reading and parsing:

- Each record (each line) contains three values: A date-time stamp, and two numeric values. You read the date-time stamp (wrongly, I'll come back to that) and then you read *six more values*.
- When you read the numeric values, you read them into a temporary `buffer`, but then you use the input stream to assign to the structure fields.
- Nowhere in the reading you handle the *comma* that separates the values.
- As with the comma, you read the date-time without consideration of the separators in the date-time format.
- You read the date-time field into separate values, then create a string of the exact same format as in the file. That's not really needed (I will tell you why below).
- The date-time is stored in the structure *as a string*, so why are you trying to parse it, if you're just storing it in a string anyway? What, if anything, does the `DateTime::Parse` function really do?

---

Now to help you with your problem there are a couple of things in the [C++ standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) that can help you. The first is the [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) function, the second is [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream).

First of all I suggest you read each line from the file complete (using `std::getline`), put the line into a `std::istringstream` and use that for the parsing, again using `std::getline`.

Something like

```
std::string line;
while (std::getline(in, line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);

    // Parse each line using the input string stream
}
```

The `std::getline` by default uses the newline as separator, but it can be told to use any single character, for example `','`: Also note that I put the date-time string directly into your structure.

```
std::getline(iss, item->datetime, ',');
```

The above two lines will put the complete date-time string into the `datetime` member variable. You can then get the two other values easily the same way:

```
std::string temp;

std::getline(iss, temp, ',');
item->open = std::stod(temp);

std::getline(iss, temp);  // Last item in input, no need for separator
item->volume = std::stoi(temp);
```

(Read about [`std::stod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) and [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).)

I randomly picked two member fields from your structure to initialize, because there are only two numeric fields per record in the file.