# Extracting time from timestamp

Tags: c, timestamp, substring, iso8601

I'm trying to extract the time section from an ISO8601 timestamp.

e.g. From the following timstamp`"0001-01-01T17:45:33"` I want to extract this part `"17:45:33"`.

Comment: Extract to where? How are your variables and functions are declared?

Comment: if you want to extract from some string then you can use strstr() but it is not clear what actually you want?

Comment: this_part = strchr(this_string, 'T')+1;

Comment: possible duplicate of [strptime() equivalent on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321849/strptime-equivalent-on-windows)

Comment: You might be better off parsing the string into a time struct so that you can then use standard library date functions to manipulate it or output it in any format you like afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a few options.

lets say you have it in a variable char array called `string`.

now if you know that it the time will always be at the end of the string it`s very easy you can just do:

```
#define  TIMEWIDTH    8
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    const char string[] = {"0001-01-01T17:45:33\0"};

    unsigned int strlength = strlen(string);

    char temp[TIMEWIDTH + 1];   // add one for null character

    printf("%s\n", string);
    strncpy(temp, string + strlength - TIMEWIDTH, TIMEWIDTH + 1);  // another + 1 for the null char
    printf("%s\n", temp);
}
```

if it's more complex you have to do some more analyzing to find it. either manually or use different available tools like `sscanf()` or something else. make sure to specifiec widths for `sscanfs()`.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sscanf.htm

if the `T` indicates the start of the time you can look for it with strchr:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    const char string[] = {"0001-01-01T17:45:33\0"};

    char *temp;

    temp = strchr(string, 'T') + 1;
    printf("%s\n", temp);
}
```

It really depends on how variable the input is... If it is just a singular example you can use either. Allthough the last one is more efficient.

You indicated that it is an ISO 8601 timestamp. then I would just use the 2nd method.