# How to convert Date string wchar_t* / LPTSTR to long timestamp

Tags: c++, date, winapi

I have a string `wchar_t` which contains the value `2015-06-01-00.00.00` or `YYYY-MM-DD-HH.MM.SS` format. I need to convert this to the timestamp which can be represented in the `long` variable.

I cannot use 3rd party libraries like `boost` or any other which I have to add a dependency of.

Please help me out with this situation.

```
LPTSTR lStr = _TEXT("2015-06-01-00.00.00");
long timestamp = convertToTimeStamp(lStr);
```

I need a function like `convertToTimeStamp`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321849/strptime-equivalent-on-windows

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe06s4ak.aspx

Comment: Thanks  @JoachimPileborg :) I found the solution from this link 
http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/lib/libc/time/strptime.c?rev=HEAD